# Increase width of image to x times of auto width

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I want to increase my image width and height to 3 times of what it actually is, but I don't know the dimension of the image. Can I do it using CSS?
I tried `calc()` function but it doesn't accept `auto`.

Comment: You can do it in % maybe? 300% is 3times more

Comment: use `transform:scale(3,3);`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this % in your style

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" style ="width:300%; height:300%">
```

or

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300%" width="300%">
```

or you can use this

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="Smiley face" class="image-class">    

<style>
    .image-class {

      transform:scale(3,3);
    }
</style>
```